# Generic class with method having generic parameter of different type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class, BaseCommunications, which has a method, SendMessage. I want to be able to use a generic type as a parameter to the SendMessage method that will depend on the type, T, of the instantiated class.

Currently, my base class is defined as:

```
public class BaseCommunications<T>
{
    public void SendMessage(<a message type depending on type of T>){}
}
```

My base class, BaseCommunications, can be implemented as one of: AMessage, BMessage, etc., while the parameter for the SendMessage method is a completely different type, as in AMessageType, BMessageType, etc. I can use an interface instead for the method parameter and make the BaseCommunications class abstract and avoid the whole generics thing. Opinions? Thoughts?

Comment: Could you post some code of what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like you want a generic BaseCommunications class that has a type argument T. The send message method should 'depend' on T...what do you mean by depend?

Comment: You really need to explain the problem better. It is unclear why `public void SendMessage(T message){}` doesn't work for you or what kind of dependency you want to have

Comment: This seems to be generics basics: `SendMessage(MyClass<T> foo)`...

Comment: If you mean that the type of the parameter of SendMessage should be `T`, then:`public void SendMessage(T msg) { someFunction(msg);}`

Comment: Sounds like you want two generic parameters, one for your class and one for your method. Where´s your problem? However as of your edit it seems you don´t even need the generic definition for your base-class `BaseCommunications`, only that one for the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s hard to understand what you are asking, but it seems you are looking for the following set up:

```
abstract class BaseCommunications<T>
{
     public void SendMessage(Message<T> message) { ... }
}
```

With this setup you can ensure that the message type will always be comlatible with the Communications class that processes it.

If `Message` can’t be made generic then you are probably better off making everything non generic to begin with because all kind of ugly runtime type checks are going to start cropping up, a sure sign that generics is not the right tool for the job.